# how to display dates from two different tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, dataview

In a DataView I am displaying two dates from two different tables in a database. Service date from maintenance table and Checklist date from fleetchecklist table.
Both columns are called Date in the database tables. The problem is its only displaying one date (checklist date). Service date should say 14/06/2015.

[image]

The SQL query works when I run it in MySql Workbench

```
 SELECT checklistitem.*,
          cl.Date As ChecklistDate,
          m1.Date AS Date
    FROM checklistitem
    LEFT JOIN maintenance m1 ON m1.CheckListID 
    LEFT JOIN Vehicle v ON m1.LinkedID = v.ID
    LEFT JOIN Trailer t ON m1.LinkedID = t.ID 
    LEFT JOIN GeneralSmall gs ON m1.TypeID = gs.ID
    LEFT JOIN fleetchecklist cl ON m1.ChecklistID = cl.ID
    WHERE m1.Company_ID = 129
```

Other code I have for the dates are:

```
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChecklistDate { get; set; }

    protected override void FillObject(DataRow dr)
   {
                    if (dr["Date"] != DBNull.Value)
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"]);
                    if (dr["ChecklistDate"] != DBNull.Value)
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ChecklistDate"]);
   }



 <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Service Date" SortExpression="Date"  dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Checklist Date" SortExpression="ChecklistDate"  dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: Change 2nd `Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ChecklistDate"]);` to ` ChecklistDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ChecklistDate"]);`

Comment: @artm  that causes both dates to display 14/05/2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning Checklist date and Service date to the same Date property. This should work:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public DateTime ChecklistDate { get; set; }

protected override void FillObject(DataRow dr)
{
    if (dr["Date"] != DBNull.Value)
        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"]);
    if (dr["ChecklistDate"] != DBNull.Value)
        ChecklistDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ChecklistDate"]);
}


<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Service Date" SortExpression="Date"  dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" SortExpression="ChecklistDate"  dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
```